# Missing libs for building firefox

Tags: firefox, compiling, gtk, libraries

I'm trying to build Mozilla Firefox by myself.
Actually I'm getting these errors.

```
 0:10.13 DEBUG: configure:7936: checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.18.0 gtk+-unix-print-2.0 glib-2.0 >= 2.42 gobject-2.0 gio-unix-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0
 0:10.13 DEBUG: configure: error: Library requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.18.0 gtk+-unix-print-2.0 glib-2.0 >= 2.42 gobject-2.0 gio-unix-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved it by installing `glib-2.0-dev`.

Comment: Better way is to ask APT to do this for you. The `sudo apt-get build-dep firefox` will install all needed dependencies for you.